# Is it possible to use the importHTML function with a concatenated URL?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate, importhtml

What I'm trying to do is use a URL previously made with the CONCATENATE function in an IMPORTHTML function. When I try:

```
importHTML (H1, "table", 0)
```

Where H1 is the cell with the concatenated URL, I get a `#VALUE!` error. Not even referencing H1 from a different sheet will work.

Any ideas about how to get past this?

According to the usual syntax, the URL needs to be enclosed in double quotes. I'm trying to set things up so I only need to type in a few lines to automatically perform IMPORTHTML runs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me:

[image: WA47779 example]

Your formula is in K4. Maybe the first part of what you are concatenating has to be a valid address itself?